# Is there a simple way to change all TIFFs to JPGs in an Indesign document?

Tags: adobe-indesign, photo-editing

I have created a zine using TIFF images. However, the images are way too big and making the file way too huge to share easily. I want to convert all the TIFFs to smaller JPGs. They are already placed in the document and there are a lot of them. Is there a way to automatically change each without placing the images again on the doc?

Answer (score 2):

1. Save zine doc, then Package. (Don’t worry about settings. We’re just doing this to get all the linked TIFF images collected to a single *Links* folder, if they are not already.)
2. Close zine doc.
3. Open all TIFFs in Photoshop, batch-convert them to the desired JPEG format. Save all new JPEGs to a single location but do not change the file name.
4. Quit PS.
5. Return to TIFF files in Finder, select all, control click and select *rename* from the menu. Add a minus or another letter to the beginning of the filenames. This breaks their link to the zine doc.
6. Place the new JPEGs in the *Links* folder.
7. Open the zine doc. It will try to link to the new JPEGs because the file name is the same except for the suffix. It will alert you that the links need to be updated. Click *update all.*

Answer (score 0):

export your file into PDF, when you click save a window with exporting settings will appear and you can change your images quality in compression tab, if you want to share the editable version of idd, just share it via wetransfer